# MySQL:memory used by query joins does not get released

Tags: mysql, join, memory, sorting, buffer-pool

I have a MySQL db running on a 8cpu 24Gb machine.
There are multiple scripts writing or reading from it at any point in time, often in parallel.

My settings:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 6
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 9663676416
innodb_log_file_size = 1073741824
read_rnd_buffer_size = 134217728
join_buffer_size = 8000000
group_concat_max_len = 100000
sort_buffer_size = 256870912
binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 21600
max_connections = 70
```

So that means 9Gb for the buffer pool, 256Mb for sort bufferand 80Mb for join buffers.
I know these are wrong settings as given the max_connections, I can totally overshoot the RAM. Mysqltuner returns:

```
Total buffers: 9.0G global + 445.0M per thread (70 max threads)
```

This was working well so far as the queries in use were not heavy on the join and sort buffers.

Last week we needed to add some functionalities and modified heavily one of the critical queries that is run every 20 mins.

The original query was looking like:

```
insert into mytable
    (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7, column7, column8, column9, column10, column11, column12)
    (SELECT * FROM 
         (select 
             column1, column2, 
             group_concat(DISTINCT column3 SEPARATOR ';') as new_column3, 
             column4, 
             date_add(column4, interval max(column5) second) as new_column5, 
             group_concat(column6 order by duration asc SEPARATOR ';') as new_column6,
             min(column7) as column7,
             0 as column8,
             .....
             from my_initial_table t 
             group by column1, column2, column4  
             having date_add(column4, interval max(column5) second) <= date_sub(now(), interval 1800 second)
             and column4 > date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 3 day)) p
         ) 
    )
```

After refactoring, we use 2 temp tables that use partitions and feed it to the initial select:

```
insert into mytable
(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column7_first_5mins, column9, column10, column11, column12, column13)

WITH source AS (
    SELECT a.*
        ,max(column6) over(partition by column1,column3) as max_per_3
        ,row_number() over(partition by column1,column3 order by column6 asc) as per_3_order 
        ,row_number() over(partition by column1 order by column6 asc) as per_1_order
        ,max(column6) over(partition by column1,x) as max_per_x
        ,row_number() over(partition by column1,x order by column6 asc) as per_x_order 
    FROM my_initial_table a
) , 1_3_history AS  (
    SELECT column1
        , JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT('column3',column3
                ,'column4',CASE WHEN per_1_order = 1 THEN column4 ELSE DATE_ADD(column4,INTERVAL max_per_3 SECOND) END
            )
    ) as history
    FROM source 
    WHERE per_3_order = 1
    GROUP BY column1
)                        
, 1_x_history AS (
    SELECT column1
        , JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT('x', x
                ,'column4',CASE WHEN per_1_order = 1 THEN column4 ELSE DATE_ADD(column4,INTERVAL max_per_x SECOND) END
            )
    ) as history
    FROM source 
    WHERE per_x_order = 1
    GROUP BY column1
)

(SELECT * FROM 
    (select 
        a.column1, a.column2, 
        group_concat(DISTINCT column3 SEPARATOR ';') as new_column3, 
        column4, 
        date_add(column4, interval max(column6) second) as new_column5, 
        max(column6) as new_column6, 
        avg(v_count) as new_column7,
        max(v_count) as new_column8,
        null as new_column7_first_5mins,
        group_concat(v_count order by column6 asc SEPARATOR ';') as new_column9,
        min(column10) as column10,
        0 as column11,
        hist.history as column12,
        hist2.history as column13
    FROM source a
    LEFT JOIN 1_3_history hist on hist.column1 = a.column1
    LEFT JOIN 1_x_history hist2 on hist2.column1 = a.column1
    group by a.column1, a.column2,  column4  
    having date_add(column4, interval max(column6) second) <= date_sub(now(), interval 10800 second)
    and column4 > date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 3 day)) p
)
```

Since we deployed this new query, the RAM usage builds up quite quickly and reach the 24Gb installed on the machine.
I definitely suspect that it comes from the sort or join buffers, however this query never run in parallel, it runs every 20 mins and run time is about 2 to 3 mins. So I would expect it to release the connection and that the sort and join buffer gets cleaned, but instead it seems like it build up.

I monitored my table open cache and it does not grow in relation to the memory consumption, so this does not look like the guilty one.

How can I dump the sort and join buffer from closed connections?
I fear that if I reduce my sort and join buffer size that will impact the performances of other queries. Any help appreciated here.

EDIT: corrected the query with the exact replica of prod, added measurements of ram from tests and explain of the whole query in json

JSON Explain:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "207154.15"
    },
    "table": {
      "insert": true,
      "table_name": "mytable",
      "access_type": "ALL"
    },
    "insert_from": {
      "table": {
        "table_name": "p",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 1841348,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 1841348,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "23019.35",
          "eval_cost": "184134.80",
          "prefix_cost": "207154.15",
          "data_read_per_join": "210M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "column1",
          "column2",
          "new_column3",
          "column4",
          "new_column5",
          "new_column6",
          "new_column7",
          "new_column8",
          "new_column7_first_5mins",
          "new_column9",
          "column10",
          "column11",
          "column12",
          "column13"
        ],
        "materialized_from_subquery": {
          "using_temporary_table": true,
          "dependent": false,
          "cacheable": true,
          "query_block": {
            "select_id": 2,
            "cost_info": {
              "query_cost": "2859846.11"
            },
            "grouping_operation": {
              "using_filesort": true,
              "cost_info": {
                "sort_cost": "1841348.00"
              },
              "nested_loop": [
                {
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "a",
                    "access_type": "ALL",
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 460337,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 460337,
                    "filtered": "100.00",
                    "cost_info": {
                      "read_cost": "5756.71",
                      "eval_cost": "46033.70",
                      "prefix_cost": "51790.41",
                      "data_read_per_join": "491M"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                      "column1",
                      "column2",
                      "column3",
                      "v_count",
                      "column4",
                      "column6",
                      "column10",
                      "title",
                      "max_per_3",
                      "per_3_order",
                      "per_1_order",
                      "max_per_x",
                      "per_x_order"
                    ],
                    "materialized_from_subquery": {
                      "using_temporary_table": true,
                      "dependent": false,
                      "cacheable": true,
                      "query_block": {
                        "select_id": 3,
                        "cost_info": {
                          "query_cost": "2353167.20"
                        },
                        "windowing": {
                          "windows": [
                            {
                              "name": "<unnamed window>",
                              "definition_position": 1,
                              "using_temporary_table": true,
                              "using_filesort": true,
                              "filesort_key": [
                                "`column1`",
                                "`column3`"
                              ],
                              "frame_buffer": {
                                "using_temporary_table": true,
                                "optimized_frame_evaluation": true
                              },
                              "functions": [
                                "max"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "<unnamed window>",
                              "definition_position": 2,
                              "using_temporary_table": true,
                              "using_filesort": true,
                              "filesort_key": [
                                "`column1`",
                                "`column3`",
                                "`column6`"
                              ],
                              "functions": [
                                "row_number"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "<unnamed window>",
                              "definition_position": 3,
                              "using_temporary_table": true,
                              "using_filesort": true,
                              "filesort_key": [
                                "`column1`",
                                "`column6`"
                              ],
                              "functions": [
                                "row_number"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "<unnamed window>",
                              "definition_position": 4,
                              "using_temporary_table": true,
                              "using_filesort": true,
                              "filesort_key": [
                                "`column1`",
                                "`x`"
                              ],
                              "frame_buffer": {
                                "using_temporary_table": true,
                                "optimized_frame_evaluation": true
                              },
                              "functions": [
                                "max"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "<unnamed window>",
                              "definition_position": 5,
                              "last_executed_window": true,
                              "using_filesort": true,
                              "filesort_key": [
                                "`column1`",
                                "`x`",
                                "`column6`"
                              ],
                              "functions": [
                                "row_number"
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          "cost_info": {
                            "sort_cost": "2301685.00"
                          },
                          "table": {
                            "table_name": "a",
                            "access_type": "ALL",
                            "rows_examined_per_scan": 460337,
                            "rows_produced_per_join": 460337,
                            "filtered": "100.00",
                            "cost_info": {
                              "read_cost": "5448.50",
                              "eval_cost": "46033.70",
                              "prefix_cost": "51482.20",
                              "data_read_per_join": "470M"
                            },
                            "used_columns": [
                              "column1",
                              "column2",
                              "column3",
                              "v_count",
                              "column4",
                              "column6",
                              "column10",
                              "x"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "hist",
                    "access_type": "ref",
                    "possible_keys": [
                      "<auto_key0>"
                    ],
                    "key": "<auto_key0>",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                      "column1"
                    ],
                    "key_length": "8",
                    "ref": [
                      "a.column1"
                    ],
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 2,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 920674,
                    "filtered": "100.00",
                    "cost_info": {
                      "read_cost": "230168.50",
                      "eval_cost": "92067.40",
                      "prefix_cost": "374026.31",
                      "data_read_per_join": "28M"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                      "column1",
                      "history"
                    ],
                    "materialized_from_subquery": {
                      "using_temporary_table": true,
                      "dependent": false,
                      "cacheable": true,
                      "query_block": {
                        "select_id": 4,
                        "cost_info": {
                          "query_cost": "3.50"
                        },
                        "grouping_operation": {
                          "using_filesort": true,
                          "table": {
                            "table_name": "source",
                            "access_type": "ref",
                            "possible_keys": [
                              "<auto_key0>"
                            ],
                            "key": "<auto_key0>",
                            "used_key_parts": [
                              "per_3_order"
                            ],
                            "key_length": "8",
                            "ref": [
                              "const"
                            ],
                            "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
                            "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
                            "filtered": "100.00",
                            "cost_info": {
                              "read_cost": "2.50",
                              "eval_cost": "1.00",
                              "prefix_cost": "3.50",
                              "data_read_per_join": "10K"
                            },
                            "used_columns": [
                              "column1",
                              "column2",
                              "column3",
                              "v_count",
                              "column4",
                              "column6",
                              "column10",
                              "title",
                              "max_per_3",
                              "per_3_order",
                              "per_1_order",
                              "max_per_x",
                              "per_x_order"
                            ],
                            "materialized_from_subquery": {
                              "sharing_temporary_table_with": {
                                "select_id": 3
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "hist2",
                    "access_type": "ref",
                    "possible_keys": [
                      "<auto_key0>"
                    ],
                    "key": "<auto_key0>",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                      "column1"
                    ],
                    "key_length": "8",
                    "ref": [
                      "a.column1"
                    ],
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 2,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 1841348,
                    "filtered": "100.00",
                    "cost_info": {
                      "read_cost": "460337.00",
                      "eval_cost": "184134.80",
                      "prefix_cost": "1018498.11",
                      "data_read_per_join": "56M"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                      "column1",
                      "history"
                    ],
                    "materialized_from_subquery": {
                      "using_temporary_table": true,
                      "dependent": false,
                      "cacheable": true,
                      "query_block": {
                        "select_id": 6,
                        "cost_info": {
                          "query_cost": "3.50"
                        },
                        "grouping_operation": {
                          "using_filesort": true,
                          "table": {
                            "table_name": "source",
                            "access_type": "ref",
                            "possible_keys": [
                              "<auto_key1>"
                            ],
                            "key": "<auto_key1>",
                            "used_key_parts": [
                              "per_title_order"
                            ],
                            "key_length": "8",
                            "ref": [
                              "const"
                            ],
                            "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
                            "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
                            "filtered": "100.00",
                            "cost_info": {
                              "read_cost": "2.50",
                              "eval_cost": "1.00",
                              "prefix_cost": "3.50",
                              "data_read_per_join": "10K"
                            },
                            "used_columns": [
                              "column1",
                              "column2",
                              "column3",
                              "v_count",
                              "column4",
                              "column6",
                              "column10",
                              "x",
                              "max_per_3",
                              "per_3_order",
                              "per_1_order",
                              "max_per_x",
                              "per_x_order"
                            ],
                            "materialized_from_subquery": {
                              "sharing_temporary_table_with": {
                                "select_id": 3
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

RAM measurements:
I tried to run the query manually 3 times in a row then waited 20 mins, and running again, giving:

```
> 12.4 -> 12.7, peak during exec at 16.4
> 12.7 -> 12.9, peak during exec at 13.8
> 12.9 -> 13.0, peak during exec at 14.1
> 
> wait 20 mins
> 
> 13.1 -> 13.3, peak at during exec 16.3
```

Comment: A) Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
F) complete www.MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report or similar. 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: B) TWENTY minutes later, Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  - not SHOW STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Wilson, I ve actually just fixed the issue. I tried reducing the read rnd buffer size to 64M, sort and join buffers to 64 and 32M, and that did the trick. Overly high sort and join buffer have a memory reservation cost too high and do not increase perf.

Comment: If you would kindly post the requested additional information, a workload analysis would be completed and suggestions provided to improve performance/stability.  READ_RND_BUFFER_SIZE at 64M is many MB greater than reasonable.

Comment: Thanks Wilson, since I solved the issue I cannot really make a before/after, but here is what you wanted to see: https://pastebin.com/9Ep9k1KH
I actually noticed that my InnoDB Read and Write buffer efficiency is way lower than before though

Comment: Vincent, Let's try gathering data again on a busy working day.  In the order listed, please. The MySQLTuner report provided was for only 1 minute and 7 seconds, was hoping you would run the report after minimum 24 hours of uptime, just after SHOW GLOBAL STATUS. Can not see in the posted data - top or htop, ulimit report, iostat report and NONE of the items from B) - SHOW GLOBAL STATUS that would have been 20 minutes later, SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST - another one, STATUS; and SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; for analysis to provide suggestions on freeing your memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vincent, In the data provided by `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`;

```
Com_group_replication_stop  0
Com_stmt_execute    1849
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    173
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    1
```

it appears you forgot to CLOSE the activity when done with execution as mentioned [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statements-in-scripts),
which releases resources used.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions on your first set:

** Remove the extra layer:

```
 SELECT * FROM ( 
               )
```

** Move this from `HAVING` to `WHERE`:

```
  column4 > date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 3 day)
```

** have this index (with the columns in this order):

```
 INDEX(column1, column2, column4)
```

Your second version seems to have a different `GROUP BY`; are you sure it delivers the same values?

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  This will show, for example, whether the "join buffer" is being used any.  If `EXPLAIN` does not tell us enough, I will ask for `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.

If there is no "swapping", then those settings are "not too big", at least for now.

As for the original question ("memory not being released")...  Check the memory after several cycles (20-minutes each).  Is the memory jumping up the first time, then not staying steady?  Is memory jumping up by the same amount each 20 minutes?  Or something in between.  (A graph would be nice, but a list of values would be OK.)

Comment: Added info as edits. Thanks for taking the time to look into it.
I have added the index as suggested (it was only on col1 before). Removing the englobing SELECT throws me errors. Then for the having, it was on an aggregate column, I corrected the query to reflect the exact one from prod, sry about that

Comment: Technically the _inner_ query was wrong since it did not have an alias.